# How can i do a concat() in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this statement, which works in SQL Server 2017:

```
REPLACE(CONCAT(NOM_TIPO_QUEBRA_ORDEM, CHAR(13), DSC_TIPO_QUEBRA_ORDEM, CHAR(13), HST_ORDEM_FILA_MOVIMENTO), CHAR(13) + CHAR(13), '') as justificativa_quebra
```

How can I do this same in SQL Server 2008, which does not support `CONCAT`?

```
REPLACE(SELECT NOM_TIPO_QUEBRA_ORDEM, CHAR(13) + DSC_TIPO_QUEBRA_ORDEM, CHAR(13) + HST_ORDEM_FILA_MOVIMENTO), CHAR(13) + CHAR(13), '' as justificativa_quebra
```

Comment: Please do not SHOUT at us; it's just rude.

Comment: Also carriage returns are helpful, you seem to know this for your output, you should treat your code this way too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONCAT(a,b,c)` is basically just syntactic sugar for `COALESCE(RTRIM(a),'') + COALESCE(RTRIM(b),'') + COALESCE(RTRIM(c),'')` ([example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fbed7e2591e1183f19cb3430d12e8f2a)).

So:

```
REPLACE
(
   CONCAT
   (
     NOM_TIPO_QUEBRA_ORDEM, CHAR(13),
     DSC_TIPO_QUEBRA_ORDEM, CHAR(13), 
     HST_ORDEM_FILA_MOVIMENTO
   ),  
CHAR(13) + CHAR(13), '') as justificativa_quebra
```

Becomes:

```
REPLACE(
    COALESCE(RTRIM(NOM_TIPO_QUEBRA_ORDEM),'') + char(13)
  + COALESCE(RTRIM(DSC_TIPO_QUEBRA_ORDEM),'') + char(13)
  + COALESCE(RTRIM(HST_ORDEM_FILA_MOVIMENTO), ''), 
CHAR(13) + CHAR(13), '') as justificativa_quebra
```

Next, send some feedback up the chain that using a database platform so famously out of support is just not a great idea.

Comment: thank u so much, Aaron, and, unfortunately i have to consume a view in a old database of another company.

Comment: "just syntactic sugar" no it isn't: nulls and conversion come to mind

Comment: @Charlieface It kind of is, I only handled the NULL aspect here, but it still replaces the need to do those things; my point wasn't to be 100% authoritative about all of the things CONCAT does, just that you can still accomplish them without CONCAT. If the question had enough information about the underlying types I would have addressed conversion too. I am just trying to solve the OP's immediate problem here, not write the wikipedia entry on CONCAT.